# @ConditionalOnMissingBean required to pick up Bean with @Primary?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an odd issue with bean definitions not being picked up the way they (from what I can tell) should be.

I have the following project and module structure:

```
* book-service
  * book-service-impl
    - com.name.service.books
      - BookService
      - ... # other configuration classes / packages   

* checkout-library
  * checkout-library-impl 
    - com.name.core.checkout
      - CheckoutManager
      - config
        - CheckoutConfiguration
    - ... # other non-configuration packages/classes
    
  * checkout-library-test
    - com.name.core.checkout.config
      - TestCheckoutConfiguration
    - ... # other non-configuration packages/classes
```

`CheckoutConfiguration`/`TestCheckoutConfiguration` look like the following:

```java
package com.name.core.checkout.config;

@Configuration
public class CheckoutConfiguration{

    @Bean
    CheckoutClient checkoutClient(CheckoutClientConfig config) {
        // ...
    }

    @Bean
    public CheckoutManager checkoutManager(final CheckoutClient checkoutClient) {
        return new CheckoutManagerImpl(checkoutClient);
    }
}
```

and:

```java
package com.name.core.checkout.config;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:checkout-test.properties")
public class TestCheckoutConfiguration {


    @Bean
    @Primary
    CheckoutClient checkoutClient(final CheckoutClientConfig config) {
        // ...
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public CheckoutManager checkoutManager(final CheckoutClient checkoutClient) {
        return new TestCheckoutManagerImpl(checkoutClient);
    }
}
```

`BookService` is started as a Spring Boot Application using:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.name"})
```

Basically, I have a "starter-like" module / artifact that, when included, should override the bean definition of `CheckoutManager` with the `@Primary` bean definition that is then picked up when  `checkout-library-test` is on the classpath.

For some reason, *these bean definitions are not used*. My `TestCheckoutConfiguration` class is scanned, but the default bean definition in `checkout-library-impl` is used instead. Seemingly, `@Primary` has no effect.

*However*, if I add `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on the bean definitions in `checkout-library-impl` in `CheckoutConfiguration`:

```java
package com.name.core.checkout.config;

@Configuration
public class CheckoutConfiguration{

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean // <---
    CheckoutClient checkoutClient(final CheckoutClientConfig config) {
        // ...
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean // <---
    public CheckoutManager checkoutManager(final CheckoutClient checkoutClient) {
        return new CheckoutManagerImpl(checkoutClient);
    }
}
```

then my bean definitions located in `checkout-library-test` / `TestCheckoutConfiguration` *are* picked up.

I do not wish to add `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on my default bean definitions, as these should not normally be overridable by the services using the library. I have intentionally not made my `test` package into an auto-configuration starter, as I feel that minor added functionality does not justify the added complexity (minor as it may be).

Is this behaviour correct? Have I missed something?

Comment: The problem is the name of the method, as that is used as a bean name/id only 1 will survive. Give your one in the test configuration a different name.

Comment: @M.Deinum That was quick :) The issue was indeed the name of the bean and adding a qualified name leads to the code working as expected. It seems I did not see the forest for the trees. If you'd like to turn your comment into an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your configuration classes define a bean named `checkoutClient` (the same for the other bean). As a bean has a unique name in this case one bean will simply override the other, leaving only 1 bean around. Which is, depending on the order of loading, probably the last one instantiated.

If you change the names of the methods, or supply a dedicated name through the `@Bean` annotation you will have both beans around. When they are both around the `@Primary` one will be picked.